# What is the fastest way to calculate sum of absolute differences between two images in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to compare images in a Python 3 application that uses Pillow and, optionally, Numpy. For compatibility reasons, I don't intend to use other external non pure-Python packages. I found this Pillow based algorithm in Roseta Code and it may serve my purpose, but it takes some time:

```
from PIL import Image

def compare_images(img1, img2):
    """Compute percentage of difference between 2 JPEG images of same size
    (using the sum of absolute differences). Alternatively, compare two bitmaps
    as defined in basic bitmap storage. Useful for comparing two JPEG images
    saved with a different compression ratios.

    Adapted from:
    http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images#Python

    :param img1: an Image object
    :param img2: an Image object
    :return: A float with the percentage of difference, or None if images are
    not directly comparable.
    """

    # Don't compare if images are of different modes or different sizes.
    if (img1.mode != img2.mode) \
            or (img1.size != img2.size) \
            or (img1.getbands() != img2.getbands()):
        return None

    pairs = zip(img1.getdata(), img2.getdata())
    if len(img1.getbands()) == 1:
        # for gray-scale jpegs
        dif = sum(abs(p1 - p2) for p1, p2 in pairs)
    else:
        dif = sum(abs(c1 - c2) for p1, p2 in pairs for c1, c2 in zip(p1, p2))

    ncomponents = img1.size[0] * img1.size[1] * 3
    return (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents  # Difference (percentage)
```

Trying to find alternatives, I discovered that this function could be rewritten using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np    
from PIL import Image

def compare_images_np(img1, img2):
    if (img1.mode != img2.mode) \
            or (img1.size != img2.size) \
            or (img1.getbands() != img2.getbands()):
        return None

    dif = 0
    for band_index, band in enumerate(img1.getbands()):
        m1 = np.array([p[band_index] for p in img1.getdata()]).reshape(*img1.size)
        m2 = np.array([p[band_index] for p in img2.getdata()]).reshape(*img2.size)
        dif += np.sum(np.abs(m1-m2))

    ncomponents = img1.size[0] * img1.size[1] * 3
    return (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents  # Difference (percentage)
```

I was expecting an improvement in processing speed, but actually it takes a little longer. I have no experience with Numpy, beyond the basics, so I wonder if there is any way to make it faster, for instance using some algorithm that does not imply that for loop. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have PIL, so will not write a full answer. But I guess you should be able to do `m1=np.array(img1.getdata()); m2=np.array(img2.getdata()); dif=np.sum(np.abs(m1-m2))` without any loops at all. You don't need to separate bands to compute absolute differences.

Comment: Take a step back. What are you trying to achieve? Do you really want to difference each of 8,000 images with the other 7,999? You'll be there for days. Consider calculating a Perceptual Hash, or a histogram precisely once for each image and then find hashes or histograms that are similar. Use parallel processing or multiple threads to accelerate stuff - all CPUs have 4-18 cores nowadays.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actually what I am trying to do is to evaluate the impact of JPEG compression, in order to decide the best value to apply before saving. I need some kind of measure of the image degradation. I have heard about SSIM, which is probably a much better algorithm for this purpose, but apparently there is currently no pure Python implementation (and I confess I don’t know how to do it myself).

Comment: My fixation with pure Python packages plus Pillow and Numpy is justified by the fact that I need my application to be able to run also on Pythonista for iOS, on my iPhone. Binary packages can’t be installed on that environment, but those two come built-in.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That’s what I suspected, but didn’t know how to do with Numpy. I will experiment with it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I did a few experiments using these alternative approaches and, actually, the fastest one seems to be the first one, based on the Rosetta Code snippet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. I have no idea of the relative performance of our two machines so maybe you can benchmark it yourself.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load images, convert to RGB, then to numpy arrays and ravel into long, flat things
a=np.array(Image.open('a.png').convert('RGB')).ravel()
b=np.array(Image.open('b.png').convert('RGB')).ravel()

# Calculate the sum of the absolute differences divided by number of elements
MAE = np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(a,b,dtype=np.float))) / a.shape[0]
```

The only "tricky" thing in there is the forcing of the result type of `np.subtract()` to a float which ensures I can store negative numbers. It may be worth trying with `dtype=np.int16` on your hardware to see if that is faster.

---

A fast way to benchmark it is as follows. Start `ipython` and then type in the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a=np.array(Image.open('a.png').convert('RGB')).ravel()
b=np.array(Image.open('b.png').convert('RGB')).ravel()
```

Now you can time my code with:

```
%timeit np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(a,b,dtype=np.float))) / a.shape[0]
6.72 µs ± 21.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Or, you can try an `int16` version like this:

```
%timeit np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(a,b,dtype=np.int16))) / a.shape[0]
6.43 µs ± 30.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

If you want to time your code, paste in your function then use:

```
%timeit compare_images_pil(img1, img2)
```

Comment: I will be running a few tests to see which approach gets faster for me. In my phone (iOS 12, Pythonista with Python 3.6.1 and some old Numpy version), it seems not to have a big impact. But maybe on desktop with more up-to-date versions it may behave differently. Both platforms are important to me.

Comment: Actually, it seems to return values that are significantly different from the other algorithms listed here. In terms of processing time, though, it seems to be about as fast as the Pillow based approach used by `diffimg`, that I reproduced in my own answer. I will do some further experimentation and, if no better approach arises, I will probably opt for the Pillow version, as that package is already one of the current dependencies for the application I am developing.

Comment: I am however a bit confused about what is the practical difference between your code sample ant the one that @ChrisLuengo places in the comments to my question. In theory they should be calculating the same sum of absolute differences between the pixel values of the two images, but the end results seem to be different. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the fact that I have forced the result of the difference calculation to float means it is more likely to be correct - I think Cris's will go wrong if the difference in any pair of pixels comes out negative.

Comment: Actually, I found that there was one missing bit in your code in order to obtain the same final result. The last line needs a division by 255 in order to achieve the same kind of ratio I was using in the examples above. Then yes, I get the same results, except for the usual rounding errors.

Comment: I have added some examples to my answer on how to benchmark things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on benchmarking with `ipython`, it really helps! It confirmed what I had determined before: on my machines, both your version and the one I posted (based on `PIL.ImageStat` and `PIL.ImageChops`) as a separate answer have quite fast times, compared with the initial two versions I had posted in my question. There seems not to be any significant difference when replacing `float` by `int16`. The version I posted seems to be a bit faster, and I probably will use it. But I am accepting this answer since it is very informative, it is a short, readable and efficient piece of code.

Comment: using `arr.sum()` instead of `np.sum(arr)` can make this operation 2 times faster

Answer (score 2):

Digging a bit, I found [this repository](https://github.com/nicolashahn/diffimg) that takes a different approach that is more based on Pillow itself and seems to give similar results.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops, ImageStat


def compare_images_pil(img1, img2):
    '''Calculate the difference between two images of the same size
    by comparing channel values at the pixel level.
    `delete_diff_file`: removes the diff image after ratio found
    `diff_img_file`: filename to store diff image

    Adapted from Nicolas Hahn:
    https://github.com/nicolashahn/diffimg/blob/master/diffimg/__init__.py
    '''

    # Don't compare if images are of different modes or different sizes.
    if (img1.mode != img2.mode) \
            or (img1.size != img2.size) \
            or (img1.getbands() != img2.getbands()):
        return None

    # Generate diff image in memory.
    diff_img = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)

    # Calculate difference as a ratio.
    stat = ImageStat.Stat(diff_img)

    # Can be [r,g,b] or [r,g,b,a].
    sum_channel_values = sum(stat.mean)
    max_all_channels = len(stat.mean) * 255
    diff_ratio = sum_channel_values / max_all_channels

    return diff_ratio * 100
```

For my test images sample, the results seem to be the same (except for a few minor float rounding errors) and it runs considerably faster than the first version I had above.